# Dropdown list, jquery selection throwing "" not defined error

Tags: php, jquery, dropdown, onchange

I am getting a `SelectChanged is not defined` message when using the following code. For the life of me, I cant figure why since I have used this before:

**jQuery**

```
jQuery("#name").on("change", function() {
   alert(this.value); 
});
```

**dropdown**

```
echo('<td class="table-font"><select id="name" onchange="SelectChanged(this)">');
foreach($Staff_On_Duty as $person){         
    $sf_name_option=$person->Staff_First_Name;
    $sl_name_option=$person->Staff_Last_Name;
    echo("<option value = $sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option");
    if (($sf_name_option == $sf_name) && ($sl_name_option == $sl_name)) echo (" selected");
    echo(">$sf_name_option&nbsp;$sl_name_option</option>"); 
}
echo("</select></td>");
```

Yes I am aware that the above method of showing the menu isn't the best, I am working on getting the functionality I need, then can make it better through separating the HTML and PHP etc

Comment: The `onchange` is looking for a globally declared function`SelectChanged()` and has nothing to do with the jQuery event listener. Note you also have a  typo in the jQuery selector which  should be `jQuery("#name").on(...`

Comment: create this function`SelectChanged()` or remove it and use the selected id `name`

Comment: Thanks. So I took out the `onchange` from the `select` and left the js as was. Now it does nothing. No errors etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: @dean I tried as above, but I also enclosed the JS in a `SelectChanged` function but it had the same result - nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do the same thing twice.

You can call a function inline using `onchange=function()` or you can add a `JQuery` event listener using `$(elem).on('change', function() {})`.

Your code is actually working (using the jquery event listener) but you are also getting an error from the attempt to run an inline function. The inline function is not defined (i.e. when the select is changed it tries to find a function called `SelectChanged` but as it has not been defined you are getting an error).

The example below shows both methods functioning.

---

```js
// Add a jquery event listener to the element with the id name, listening for any change
jQuery("#name").on("change", function() {

  // Print the value of the element
  console.log("From JQuery function: " + this.value);

});


// Function that can be called inline using onchange = "SelectChanged(this)"
function SelectChanged(el) {

  // Print the value of the inline element
  console.log("SelectChanged function: " + el.value);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td class="table-font">
  <select id="name" onchange="SelectChanged(this)">

    <option value="Firstname Surname 1" selected>Firstname Surname 1</option>
    <option value="Firstname Surname 2">Firstname Surname 2</option>
    
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#name").change("#name")

function SelectChanged() {
     alert(this.value); 
}
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)